# Using multiple Boolean variables in R script within QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, r, qgis-processing, rqgis

I am testing the capabilities to run my R script in QGIS. I am facing a basic question.

I am defining a dropdown menu with all the parameters for a specific variable:

```
##test1=group
##Sensor?=selection S1;S2;S1 AND S2
```

[image]

Then I use this basic code to test if I can use the selection of the user within an `if statement`

```
if (S1){
print("It is working")
}
```

My script is not working and is reporting the following error. Any idea how this type of variables can be used in a `if statement`. Shoud I use a reguluar `boolean variable`. If so, how should it be implemented?

```
Sensor?=0
Error: unexpected '=' in "Sensor?="
Execution halted
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm [Unnamed algorithm] finished
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found the solution,

```
##test1=group
##Sensor=selection S1;S2;S1 AND S2

if (Sensor == "S1"){
print("It is working")
}
```

I think there is little information or non-unified place to find documentation about the implementation of R scripts in QGIS. If you find a good guide, please feel free to add it on the comments.

--- EDIT ---

Based on another post ([Using if statement in R script within QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313780/using-if-statement-in-r-script-within-qgis/313811?noredirect=1#comment509841_313811))

```
##test1=group
##Sensor=selection S1;S2;S1 AND S2

if (Sensor == 0){
print("It is working")
}
```

works as well taking into account the `python` indexing rule

Comment: Actually posting an answer to your own question so others can use it. Hero.

Comment: @TeddyTedTed, I think it happens to me as well. Sometimes the solution is much simpler than you expected. But when you are lost you are normally trying to implement any possible approaches to achieve the result that you are striving for. And then at some point, you see that miserable answer hidden in your `"Learn by falling, falling, ... , falling, trying, and achieving"` method. And IMHO it is always better when you find solution/answering your own question by yourself.

Comment: @Taras I definitely agree, very satisfying to finally figure something out as well. My previous comment was meant as praise for GCGM posting an answer to their own question, sorry for any confusion.