# Using if statement in R script within QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing, rqgis

I am creating an R script in QGIS and I am facing an issue with an `if statement`. First, I declare the input from the user

```
##Which_S2_bands_do_you_want_to_use=selection 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 12;2 3 4 8 11 12
```

Later I use it in the following condition:

```
if (Which_S2_bands_do_you_want_to_use == "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 12") {
        bands<-c("B((0[2348]_10m)|(((0[567])|(1[12])|(8A))_20m)).jp2$")}
```

And use it in the following code:

```
  S2<-list.files(S2, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern=bands)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error in list.files(S2, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = bands) :
object 'bands' not found
Execution halted
```

It seems the `if statment` is not been run. Any idea what could be the reason?

Maybe another approach to use the input from the user as a condition to change a variable in the script?

Comment: I think that the `selection` parameter type returns an integer corresponding to the position of the selection. See this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/220078/70980. So if the user selects the first option it returns 0, the second option returns 1, and so on. You can verify this by adding a print statement with your parameter variable at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new R processing provider, when you give the user selection options, the options are returned as integers starting with 0 (Python indexing format - not R's which would start with 1!).

This should work:

```
if (Which_S2_bands_do_you_want_to_use == 0) {
    bands<-c("B((0[2348]_10m)|(((0[567])|(1[12])|(8A))_20m)).jp2$")}
```

Note that your original code should have worked in QGIS 2.18 and the old R provider!

Comment: Good to know, indeed it is working now. Just for reference, I am using QGIS v. 2.18.18 and R 3.5.2

Comment: Which R provider version are you using, though?

Comment: Working on Ubuntu, from `Processing - Options - Providers - R` I cannot see the version been used. Having only R 3.5.2 installed and that the log file prints  `R execution console output R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"` I would assume this is the R version QGIS is running